# How do I enable https in Spring Boot 3 native image?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, graalvm-native-image, spring-native

With Spring Boot 2 and its experimental native support I used to have `@NativeHint(options = "--enable-https")` at the top of my application's "main" class to tell it to enable https support in the GraalVM image.

It seems in Spring Boot 3/Spring 6 that annotation has been removed and I can not figure out how to achieve the same behavior. I've looked through https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/native-image.html and haven't found anything in there either.

I tried creating a `RuntimeHintsRegistrar` bean, but the `RuntimeHints` class doesn't seem to have anything in there that seems appropriate.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything as `spring-web` now contains [Graal configuration metadata to enable HTTPS by default](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/resources/META-INF/native-image/org.springframework/spring-web/native-image.properties)

Comment: Thank you! If you'd like to add that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

@Andy Wilkinson posted the answer in comments:

You shouldn't need to do anything as `spring-web` now contains [Graal configuration metadata to enable HTTPS by default](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/resources/META-INF/native-image/org.springframework/spring-web/native-image.properties)